# PDO in PHP, how to improve this PDO mysql code

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring, pdo

Thanks for checking. All helpful answers/comments are up voted.
I have the following code, which does the job, but imo is not efficient. The reason I think it's not efficient is because I'm using fetchAll + loop **even though I know that the query will return either 1 or no records.**

```
//assume the usual new PDO, binding, and execute are up here

$myval = "somevalue";

$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$res) {
    //no record matches
    //BLOCK A CODE HERE
} else { 
    //found matching record (but always going to be 1 record, no more)  
    foreach($res as $row) {
        if ($myval == $row['val']){
            //myval is the same as db
            //BLOCK B CODE HERE
        } else {
            //myval is different from db
            //BLOCK C CODE HERE
        }
    }//foreach
}
```

How can I improve it to remove the bulky look of the foreach and fetchAll (considering I know it's always going to be 1 or 0 record only)? But I still need similar checkpoints so I can execute the same `BLOCK A` `BLOCK B` `BLOCK C` as my current logic needs it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$myval = "somevalue";

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$row) {
    //no record matches
    //BLOCK A CODE HERE
} else if ($myval == $row['val']) { 
    //myval is the same as db
    //BLOCK B CODE HERE
} else {
    //myval is different from db
    //BLOCK C CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will rewrite it in following way:

```
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$first_row = ( count($res) ? $res[0] : null );
if ( is_null($first_row) ) {
    // nothing found code
}
else {
    // we found something
    if ($myval == $first_row['val']) {
         // result is good
    }
    else {
         // result is bad
    }
}
```

Also I'll [enable `PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) to throw exceptions for all errors:

```
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

So I'll not need check errors for each `PDO` result. Just `try/catch` block in main function. Somewhere at top level of the code:

```
try {
    // main script logic
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    // sql error appeared somewhere, we should save it for futher investigation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to deal with no more than one row, you could use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use native SQL for your statement and prepare it:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE specificVal = ?
```

If you did this, you can use `->fetch` instead of `->fetchAll` and also use `->bindParam`.
And `->prepare` makes it easy to deal with ANY `$myVa`l, because you can run the statement as often as you want.
You just have to chance the `?` by using another params.

Example:

```
$stmt->prepare($yourQuery);
$stmt->bindParam($one,$two);

if($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
// here you can access $two (the result)
}
elseif(empty($two) || !checkForOtherComparisons($two))
{
// here you go if $two is not available or does not match to any other logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

This will fetch just the first row.

Since you know for sure it will return only 1 or 0 rows it is likely safe to use this.